# Какой тип подчинения придаточных в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

*Не та собака кусает, что лает, а та , что молчит и хвостом виляет.*

Answer (score 1):

Неоднородное подчинение местоимённо-определительных придаточных, относящихся к однородным членам главного[Не та - = , (что ), а та] , (что ).

Вот в книге С.Ивановой "Экзаменационные ловушки" приводится анализ похожего предложения с неоднородным подчинением:если придаточные предложения одного типа относятся к разным словам в главном предложении, то одно из них разрывает главное.

[Самые богатые из людей не те, (кто получал много), а те],(кто как раз щедрей всех других раздавал себя людям)/(Леонов)/

По-моему, конструкция очень похожа.

Comment: А схема будет такой :   [  , ( что ) ,  ] , ( что ).

Comment: Да, верно:  [Не та - = , (что ), а та] , (что ).

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется, что здесь  сложное сочинение (с союзом А) двух СПП с придаточными определительными, но при этом главное предложение во втором СПП  является неполным:
Не та собака кусает, что лает, а та (собака кусает) , что молчит и хвостом виляет.

Общая модель  одного СПП с придаточным определительным:  [ К + сущ.], (союзное слово), ТА - указательное слово (коррелят).

Comment: А какое в таком случае , подчинение придаточных? Я думаю , что последовательное. Но я не уверена.

Comment: Если принять предложенную схему, то  в ней нет последовательного или параллельного подчинения. Есть два СПП, связанных частицей НЕ и союзом А,  и главное  предложение в каждом из них имеет одно собственное придаточное. Общая схема:  Не [ К + сущ.], (союзное слово), а [ К + сущ.], (союзное слово). А вообще-то интересный вопрос,  странно, что участники НЕ ВЫСКАЗЫВАЮТ СВОЕГО МНЕНИЯ.  Мне, например, приведенный вариант ответа совершено непонятен.

Comment: Вера,а что непонятно? Чем отличаются предложения с однородными членами от неполных двусоставных? (Кто? )собака.(Что делает? ) кусает.(Какая собака? ) не та, (что лает), а та,( что хвостом виляет).-однородные определения.А вот если бы было:  Та собака лает, а та хвостом виляет - это неполное двусоставное.

Comment: Вот у Валгиной примеры однородных членов, которые тоже можно перепутать с неполными двусоставными, если их восполнить по Вашему примеру:Прошло уже не семь, а (прошло)целых двенадцать лет (Т.
Из горницы ... порой слышался чей-то глухой ночной вздох, а то (слышался)легкий стон (Нагиб.)   Не только охотники, но и рыбаки ждут так же нужного времени года… (Сол.) Изменились не планы, а (изменилось)настроение.

Comment: В вузовской грамматике 2012 года по поводу предложений с однородными сказуемыми приводятся два возможных решения, и в каждом конкретном случае вопрос решается с учетом различных факторов. В этом предложении большая расчлененность, распространенность частей, противительные отношения между  ними говорят против однородности, приближая предложение к сложному составу. Другой вопрос о том, что это не местоименно-определительные, а определительные придаточные с указательным словом. Как-то неловко одну часть считать определительным придаточным, а другую - местоименно-определительным.

Comment: Не та собака кусает, что лает, а та , что молчит и хвостом виляет.-Вера, побойтесь бога, какая распространённость? И противительные отношения не могут говорить против однородности:Собака не лает, а в дом не пускает - разве не однородные члены? А здесь речь  не об однородных сказуемых, а об однородных определениях не та, а та, всё равно что" не рыжая собака кусает, а чёрная". Здесь оба местоимённо-определительные. Если бы было местоимение ТАКОЙ, тогда было бы определительным, а ТОТ, ТЕ, ТО, ВСЯКИЙ,КАЖДЫЙ,ЛЮБОЙ, ВСЕ, МНОГИЕ ИЗ ТЕХ-это мест.-определительные по правилам.

Comment: Вы почитайте свой вузовский учебник повнимательнее, может, там РГ-80? Там совсем другое представление.

Comment: К сожалению, в вузовском учебнике (Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка") совершенно другие представления о видах СПП. Там они названы 1) присубстантивно -атрибутивными (указательные слова относятся к существительным, разные бывают типы: такой/тот - какой/который) и 2) местоименно-соотносительными (тот - кто, те -что, указательные слова сами образуют местоименную пару). Именно такое представление мне кажется современным и научным, да и обычному школьному оно не противоречит, терминология только посложнее.

Comment: К учебнику претензий не имею, но там нет утверждения, похожего на Ваше.

Comment: Тогда можно взять школьный учебник для 9 класса (Бархударов и др., 1999 год), там различают придаточные определительные и местоименно-определительные. "Та собака, что" - это определительное, "та, что" - это местоименно-определительное, но лучше считать, что это неполное предложение (пропущенное слово восстанавливается из текста). Тогда оба определительные.  Это всё, что я могу сказать по этому  вопросу. Но получается. что слов говорится/повторяется  много, а ясности не прибавляется.